# Access a topology sample code runtime error when define ITopologyExtension

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, topology

I encountered a runtime error when I used the sample code from ESRI on Accessing a topology. The sample code is as follows:

```
Dim topoUiD As UID = New UIDClass
topoUiD.Value = "esriEditorExt.TopologyExtension"
Dim m_application As IApplication   ' this line is added by me
Dim topologyExt As ITopologyExtension = CType(m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(topoUiD),  ITopologyExtension)
Dim topology As ITopology
topology = CType(topologyExt.CurrentTopology, ITopology)
```

A runtime error occurs when execute:  Dim topologyExt As ITopologyExtension = CType(m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(topoUiD),  ITopologyExtension

I guess it is caused by the definition of m_application, anybody can tell me how to define it? thanks.

Comment: What is the runtime error? Is m_application set to something? What level of license are you using? TopologyExtension is not available for Basic (View) license.

Comment: I even don't have a chance to see the runtime error, it just close the ArcMap directly. From the example, I don't know what should set to the m_application. I am using standard license.

Comment: dim m_application as IApplication = ArcMap.Application assuming you are using an add-in.

Comment: Thanks Michael, with your kindly help I can successfully access a topology. I am using a add-in and very new to it so many silly questions.

Comment: We all started somewhere. Don't be ashamed of a 'silly' mistake we've all made mistakes before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify the comments, the problem is that you have an IApplication object but haven't linked it to ArcMap (initialized the object):

```
Dim topoUiD As UID = New UIDClass
topoUiD.Value = "esriEditorExt.TopologyExtension"
Dim m_application As IApplication =  My.ArcMap.Application  ' initialize the object
Dim topologyExt As ITopologyExtension = CType(m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(topoUiD),  ITopologyExtension)
Dim topology As ITopology
topology = CType(topologyExt.CurrentTopology, ITopology)
```

The object is created an initialized: `Dim m_application As IApplication =  My.ArcMap.Application`, note in C# `My` is not used and it's `IApplication m_application = ArcMap.Application;`

[Here is a link showing how to start an Add in](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001ms000000).

[Here is a link to the ArcMap object](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ESRI_ArcGIS_ArcMap/000t00000003000000/)

In your add in it's important to link to the current application/document using My.ArcMap.IApplication ([IApplication](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IApplication_Interface/00230000002w000000/)) or the other important one My.ArcMap.Document (an [IMXDocument](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMxDocument_Interface/000v0000010w000000/))

You can condense these two lines:

```
Dim m_application As IApplication =  My.ArcMap.Application  ' initialize the object
Dim topologyExt As ITopologyExtension = CType(m_application.FindExtensionByCLSID(topoUiD),  ITopologyExtension)
```

into:

```
Dim topologyExt As ITopologyExtension = CType(My.ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(topoUiD),  ITopologyExtension)
```

As long as you don't need the m_application object later.